# Having issue in updating xcode vesion 9.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-elcapitan, xcode9

Is it necessary to update OS X El Capitan for updating xcode version 9.0.1 ?

can anyone know this thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html you can see the requirements for Xcode 9.0.1:

> Xcode 9 requires a Mac running macOS 10.12.6 or later.

So, yes, you have to update at least to macOS Sierra unfortunately. OS X El Capitan is version 10.11.

Comment: can you please accept the answer if it did help you? Thanks!

Comment: okay but bro i have mac OS X EL Capitan 10.11.6 still i am not able to download it. It's just shows me progress indicator but not actually installing

Comment: You NEED macOS Sierra for installing it. First install Sierra, then Xcode 9.